# preg_match string from sentence if title has certain word

Tags: php, preg-match

i want to preg_match "8t5562g" of the second sentence where title has a word similar to "Music"

```
</div><div class="content"><h3 class="title "><a href="9JGl134" class="ellipsis" data-sessionlink="vij0JFIDY2Jj"  title="Drama_Live - Drama Live " rel="prefetch" dir="ltr">#Drama_Live - Drama Live</a></h3>

    </div><div class="content"><h3 class="title "><a href="8t5562g" class="ellipsis" data-sessionlink="vdshds4452Jj"  title="Music_Live - Music Live " rel="prefetch" dir="ltr">#Music_Live - Music Live</a></h3>
```

Tried this but didn't worked

```
$likes = preg_match("'herf=\"(.*?)\"'si", $data, $matches);
$like = "($matches[1])";       
print $like;
```

but it gives me href of first sentence not what i want. Any Idea ?

Comment: Why don't you use a DOM parser?

Comment: Is it time for [*the* answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) again?

Comment: `"'herf=\"(.*?)\"'si"` ... are you really using apostrophes as delimiters? ... and you probably want `href` rather than `herf` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

`$likes = preg_match("#href=\"(.*?)\".*usic#si", $data, $matches);`

The first group will be your result

Comment: I Tried It and It Worked! Thanks